# Why am I getting this error for the keydown()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#promptButton").click(function(){
    $("#openPrompt").hide();
    startGame();
  });
});

function startGame(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#gameboard").append("<div class='snakeHead' id='head'> hi </div>");
  var direction;
  moveTimer = setInterval(function() {snakeMove()},1000);
  function snakeMove(){
    function snakeDirection(){
      $(".snakeHead").keydown(function(key){
        if (key.which === 38){
            direction = "up";
            return {"margin-top": "-=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 40){
            direction = "down"
            return {"margin-top": "+=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 37){
            direction = "left"
            return {"margin-left": "-=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 39){
            direction = "right"
            return {"margin-left": "+=20px"}
        } else {
            direction = "right"
            return {"margin-left": "+=20px}"
        };
      });
    };
    $('.snakeHead').animate({'margin-left':'+=20px'}, 'slow');
  }
  });
};
```

I keep getting

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')' on line 32 col 11.

I was under the impression that `keydown()` only needed to be called with the function that would be call when the event triggered. Do I need another expression to call it with?

Thanks for helping, this is my first real project that I'm trying and I'm self-taught, so try to be as clear as possible for me. Thanks!

Comment: It will help people to answer your question if you point out which line in your example is line 32.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with event handlers, it's a syntax error.  You're missing a closing bracket `)` somewhere.  Try autoformatting your code, and the mistake will stick out :)

Comment: First of all, you don't need to wrap the code inside your `startGame` function in a `document.ready` function - calling the function within the `document.ready` call at the top *ensures* the document is ready before invoking the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error:

```
function startGame(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#gameboard").append("<div class='snakeHead' id='head'> hi </div>");
  var direction;
  moveTimer = setInterval(function() {snakeMove()},1000);
  function snakeMove(){
    function snakeDirection(){
      $(".snakeHead").keydown(function(key){
        if (key.which === 38){
            direction = "up";
            return {"margin-top": "-=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 40){
            direction = "down"
            return {"margin-top": "+=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 37){
            direction = "left"
            return {"margin-left": "-=20px"}
        } else if(key.which === 39){
            direction = "right"
            return {"margin-left": "+=20px"}
        } else {
            direction = "right"
            return {"margin-left": "+=20px}" <--- Here --->
        };
      });
    };
    $('.snakeHead').animate({'margin-left':'+=20px'}, 'slow');
  }
  });
};
```